# Where do the *.wav files need to live in the directory?

Tags: java, wav, javasound

I am working on sound code for a game.  And I was using the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

/**
 * This enum encapsulates all the sound effects of a game, so as to separate the sound playing
 * codes from the game codes.
 * 1. Define all your sound effect names and the associated wave file.
 * 2. To play a specific sound, simply invoke SoundEffect.SOUND_NAME.play().
 * 3. You might optionally invoke the static method SoundEffect.init() to pre-load all the
 *    sound files, so that the play is not paused while loading the file for the first time.
 * 4. You can use the static variable SoundEffect.volume to mute the sound.
 */
public enum SoundEffect {
   EXPLODE("explode.wav"),   // explosion
   GONG("gong.wav"),         // gong
   SHOOT("shoot.wav");       // bullet

   // Nested class for specifying volume
   public static enum Volume {
      MUTE, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
   }

   public static Volume volume = Volume.LOW;

   // Each sound effect has its own clip, loaded with its own sound file.
   private Clip clip;

   // Constructor to construct each element of the enum with its own sound file.
   SoundEffect(String soundFileName) {
      try {
         // Use URL (instead of File) to read from disk and JAR.
         URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(soundFileName);
         // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
         AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
         // Get a clip resource.
         clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioInputStream);
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   // Play or Re-play the sound effect from the beginning, by rewinding.
   public void play() {
      if (volume != Volume.MUTE) {
         if (clip.isRunning())
            clip.stop();   // Stop the player if it is still running
         clip.setFramePosition(0); // rewind to the beginning
         clip.start();     // Start playing
      }
   }

   // Optional static method to pre-load all the sound files.
   static void init() {
      values(); // calls the constructor for all the elements
   }
}
```

Now when I replace one of the listed *.wav files from the code with my own or even name one of my own to the file name listed from the above code.  I receive the follow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at soundTest.main(soundTest.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at SoundEffect.<init>(sfx.java:75)
    at SoundEffect.<clinit>(sfx.java:55)
```

From following the stack URL url is null going in, which is telling me the *.wav file itself is not being read.

I have tried the following lines and yes the *.wav file was present (I am aware that I cannot have three items named the same, I've used one played with it, then commented it out and try again with another one, I just removed the "//" to make is easier to read):

```
TEST("file://C:/shoot.wav");
TEST("/soundTest/shoot.wav");
TEST("shoot.wav");
```

As well as, placing a copy of the file in the directory with the package (default), in the src folder, and of course in the root (c:).

How I am envoking the enum is in my main statement where it is all the standard java, main code but with:

```
 SoundEffect.SHOOT.play();
```

Where exactly does the *.wav file need to be at int he directory?  Or if there is another issue I am missing please point it out.  I am also using the Eclipse IDE "Kepler," on Windows 8.1.  I would like to note the posted code is all I have thus far.

Comment: Based on your example, the files need to be stored in the default package. Having said that, I believe for Eclipse, you need to create a "resources" folder in your projects root and place resources you want to be included within the Jar in it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so correct me if I am wrong on this, I could just drag and drop the file, to the package_Name and then I just invoke it like the comment says?  Because I have tried that and the same error.

Comment: If I understand Eclipse properly (I'm not a user of it), you need to create a "resources" directory in the top level of your project.  In this, you need to create a directory structure which is the same as `SoundEffect`'s package structure.  Then drop your files into this, clean and build...fingers crossed

Comment: Ok seems like Eclipse might be the problem, would you have any recommendations on something to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is some discussion in the comments that Eclipse might be the problem. I seriously doubt Eclipse is the problem. I have loaded hundreds of audio files using Eclipse. Usually I put the files in a sub-directory "audio" that is one level below the calling code, and use the relative address form: "audio/mySound.wav".

Here is how I load my URL:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("audio/" & fileName);
```

I am puzzled as to why there are MIDI references in your stack trace. MIDI has nothing to do with loading .wav files, and really should not be involved at all. Are you sure this is the correct stack trace? Why are we seeing references to MIDI?

Sometimes an unrecognizable .wav file format will throw unexpected errors. The most common .wav is 16-bit encoding, 44100 bps, stereo, little-endian. Are your .wav files of this format?

There are some aspects of your code that I haven't seen implemented in this manner, particularly the use of ENUMS. I'll take your word all that has been tested and verified. I tend to just name individual sound objects (using a wrapper for wav files with Clip or SourceDataLine for playback) and use them that way. Could be what you have with that is a good organizational tool, but I'm not clear if it is working as intended.

For example, with Static use of SoundEffect, as in SoundEffect.SHOOT.play(), are you sure it is pointing to the shoot.wav? Have you written a test to verify this? Combining ENUMS and static invocations--it's getting a little tricky for me to follow.

Comment: thank you for the reply, how I came across that code is, from another group member he upped and left so I am playing with the code he left us to see if anything is useable.  I does seem a lot simpler then other "game audio code" I've seen.  I'll try your URL suggestion, and get back with you tomorrow.  And I'll double check the *.wav file, to see if it is a valid type JAVA can play.

Comment: You might laugh at this, but it was the actual *.wav file itself, not supported via java.  SMH  But also turns out there is more to the code, no it run without errors but doesn't output the sound.

Comment: Sometimes I laugh in order to avoid crying. I was very frustrated and annoyed the first time I was bit by this very issue. My DAW prefers to export .wavs with 32-bit encoding and I had a difficult time figuring this out, since I was still new to Java audio and not secure in my understanding of the code. Part of the issue is the way mediocre coding will wrap errors within other errors such that it is hard to find the root cause: one of the bugaboos of using found code.

Comment: Now with the issue of now sound playing, would I be correct to assume, that there is more to that code, and I would need to open a audio channel to play the given sound?

Comment: It looks to me like the Clip is being opened upon instantiation. Maybe a good way to trouble-shoot would be to rewrite the code without the ENUMs. Make it something that plays back a single wav (which you specify in the instantiation). That is what I would do. Just to be clear, the original code with the original three files works okay?

Comment: It works like a champ now.  What I had to do is put the thread to sleep, I tried 5 seconds, and it worked.  This is what I did in my main: sfx.init(); sfx.TEST.play(); Thread.sleep(3000);'code'  Thank You, for your feedback and help.